# File Creation of Acceptable JPEGs for FFMPEG With Appropriate Names in Python Fails

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am generating jpeg files periodically and saving them in sequential order to be processed into a video by FFMPEG using the command line. The still images are constructed using a Python 2.7 program running Raspian on an RPi and saved in an attached folder on a Windows PC. FFMPEG is run on that PC from within the folder containing the JPEGS.

The JPEGs are created with a line of code like this:

```
image_name= '%d.jpg'%(image_number)
```

where image number is incremented for each JPEG. Then in FFMPEG the command is:

```
ffmpeg -r 15 -i %d.jpg -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -filter:v scale=640:480 timelapse_15fps_noca.mp4
```

Visually the files look correct they are simply 0.jpg, 1.jpg, etc., However FFMEG fails to process the files giving an error something like "Could find no  file with path '%d.jpg' and index in the range 0-4"

HOWEVER (!) if I rename the files in my file manager (Directory Opus) in sequence (it defaults to leading zeros so I have to change the %d.jpg to %4d.jpg, FFMPEG processes the video perfectly!

I believe that FFMPEG does not interpret the filename correctly. I have also produced the filename by concatenating the string value of the number with the jpg extension, produced the filename with leading zeros etc., Nothing has worked. Renaming them in DOPUS works like a charm. I just do not understand the problem. Any help appreciated

Comment: If you're typing the command into the command line, be aware that `%` has special meaning. Replace `ffmpeg` with `echo` to see how the command line is interpreted.

Comment: Share full log of your attempt.

Comment: I seem to have found the problem. I this operation the RPi software is storing the JPEGs in a folder located in the Win7 PC linked on startup via the fstab file. It appears as if one or more of the files was corrupted and that, not the file names was the problem. Repeated the experiment this AM using a new folder created by the program & files and FFMEG did not burp and instead created a perfect video. So syntax was  not the problem. Thanks for the 'echo' tip; I had not thought of that!

Comment: Correction to my statement the problem is solved. I believe Mark is correct the issue is the % in the FFMPEG statement. It is not being interpreted as a formatting symbol but acting as it would in a DOS batch file. I got the error again after running FFMPEG from a batch file called dailyvideo.cmd  the error  statement was: "No such file or folder 'dailyvideo.cmdd.jpg' so the %0d.jpg is being misinterpreted. I need to force a literal translation of the FFMPEG reference. How to do?

Comment: So following on from my comment above...taking Mark's suggestion about the % character in FFMPEG, I 'escaped' the % character by using two %'s in succession so the -i %0d.jpg became -i %%0d.jpg and FFMPEG ran as expected.....PROBLEM SOLVED!!!! THANK YOU!!!!